# Numa estrutura de lista encadeada, por que é utilizado um ponteiro para o ponteiro do nó?

Tags: c, ponteiro, struct, lista-encadeada

Ao ler os slides de meu professor fiquei com uma dúvida em relação desta estrutura:

```
struct node
{
    char item;
    struct node *next;
};
typedef struct node Node;
typedef node *Lista;
```

Não ficou claro para mim, o motivo do `typedef node *Lista`, pois me parecia já haver um ponteiro para a próxima `struct`. Alguém poderia me explicar o porquê?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Lista` é um tipo para organizar a lista, ele não é a próxima estrutura, é a primeira, é onde inicia a lista. Se todo nó é acessado por meio de um ponteiro, como o primeiro nó é acessado? Por um ponteiro externo. É só isso. Não há bem um ponteiro para ponteiro, há só um ponteiro para um estrutura, que dentro tem um outro ponteiro.

Comment: Então `Lista` seria um ponteiro previamente criado para acessar o primeiro elemento?
Por que eu não poderia fazer isso apenas fazendo um node->next?

Comment: Seria isto. Você não pode fazer o acesso direto porque não tem um item quando começa. Na verdade, se você quer fazer isso é você que tem que dizer como fará, eu não vejo como conseguiria.